# connect python package with credentials file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am creating a python package with multiple functions that require certain credentials. I am wondering how I can use login info in a credentials file and connect to that. I also want it so that anyone can use my package and load their own credentials into the file.

Before this package was installable via pip, I used to have all the information stored in a seperate .py file. However, since I want to be able to install this package through pip, and have others do the same, this option won't work

Answer (score 0):

One way I've seen this accomplished is by adding an empty .py file, such as `config.py` with empty variables, to your repo.

```
username = ""
password = ""
```

From there you would simply access `config.username` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the libray os and use the .env implementation.

In this way,  the use will have a .env file with:

USERNAME= "username "
PASSWORD = "password" and the programs will be able to read it.

More info and tutorial can be found here:

https://able.bio/rhett/how-to-set-and-get-environment-variables-in-python--274rgt5